# How do I pass the result of a query to a variable (as a string) with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

So I have an issue. I'm trying to verify if a password is valid for a simple Flask web application.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():

    if request.method == 'POST':

        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']

    user_password = db.session.query(User.password).filter(User.username == username).first()

    if password != str(user_password):
        return "The password is invalid."
    else:
        return "Login successful."
```

But this doesn't work... It's always invalid and I think that I know why. The user_password query actually doesn't return the password as a string. If the password is Hello1234, it returns ('Hello1234',). What I need is for the user_password to just get the returned row as a string so that I can compare it with the user input.

How can I do that?

Comment: use `user_password[0]` - ie. `if password != user_password[0]:` BTW: but you may have to check if you get any value in `user_password` before you use `[0]` because you may get empty result and then `[0]` will give error. `if user_password and password != user_password[0]:`

Comment: I must *urge you* not to save passwords as plain text in your database. Please do not perpetuate the cycle.

Comment: Make sure you understand the return type from the big db query chained function calls. You aren't getting a string back, that's a tuple with a string as it's first member.

Comment: @sleblanc I must let you know this is FOR TESTING PURPOSES ONLY and it's for a personal project while I'm learning. This is not going into production.

Comment: instead of .`first()`, you could use `.scalar()` to retrieve the scalar value in the first row, otherwise pick the 0th element in the tuple using `user_password[0]`

Answer (score 2):

If you get tuple `('Hello1234',)` then use index `[0]` to get first element from tuple `('Hello1234',)[0]`

```
if password != user_password[0]:
```

---

**BTW:** I don't know what it gives when there is no password in database - empty tuple or `None` or raise error but if it gives empty tuple or `None` then you should first check if there is something before you can use `[0]`

```
if user_password and password != user_password[0]:
```

Comment: Yeah this worked.

Comment: By the way, I have a query to search for the username first, if the row count = 0, then the user does not exist, if it's > 1 then there's a problem and if it's = 1 then the username exists, then the next step is to check if the password is valid.

Comment: you don't have to check if user exists because you should get same result when you get password (without `first()`) and check `len(user_password)`

Comment: `.first()` will simply return `None` when the result set is empty. Note: usually, you would want to use `.one_or_none()` as it will catch programming errors when unexpectedly returning more than one record, facilitating debugging, instead of silently discarding the additional records.

Comment: @sleblanc Thanks for that. I'll have a look into it.

Answer (score 1):

When SQLAlchemy returns a row, it never returns individual values, but always a standalone row. You must therefore extract the value from the row, or compare it to a tuple that contains the same values.

```
form_username = request.form['username']
form_password = request.form['password']

row = db.session.query(User.password).filter(User.username == form_username).one_or_none()

if row is None:
    print("You are not part of our secret club")

else:
    crypted_password = row[0]

    # def check_password(plaintext, crypted) → bool

    if check_password(form_password, crypted_password):
        print("Access granted")
    else:
        print("Don't try to hack me!")
```

Alternatively, you can check for username and password in one go. This method does not work as well because the password checking  function usually needs to know a salt that is stored along the hashed password inside the database.

The whole 'fetch user if exists, then validate password' scheme exists only because of salted, hashed password storage, otherwise, you should minimize round-trips to the database and do all your transaction in as few queries as possible.

```
form_username = request.form['username']
form_password = request.form['password']

row = db.session.query(User.name).filter(
        User.username == form_username,
        User.password == form_password).one_or_none()

if row is None:
    print("Username or password invalid.")
else:
    print("Welcome aboard, %s.".format(row[0]))
```